# coverage in parallel for django tests

Tags: django, coverage.py

I am running the following through a `Makefile`:

```
NPROCS:=$(shell /usr/bin/nproc)

.PHONY: coverage-app
coverage-app:
    coverage erase --rcfile=./.coveragerc-app
    coverage run --parallel-mode --rcfile=./.coveragerc-app manage.py test -v 3 --parallel=$(NPROCS) app
    coverage combine --rcfile=./.coveragerc-app
    coverage report -m --rcfile=./.coveragerc-app
```

If I set `NPROCS` to 1, I get the expected 100% test coverage of all files within `app`. However, if `NPROCS` is greater than 1, I get lots of missing lines in my report.

What am I doing wrong?

My `.coveragerc-app` is as follows:

```
# Control coverage.py
[run]
branch = True
omit = */__init__*
       */test*.py
       */migrations/*
       */urls.py
       app/admin.py
       app/apps.py
source = app
parallel = true

[report]
precision = 1
show_missing = True
ignore_errors = True
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    raise NotImplementedError
    except ImportError
    def __repr__
    if self\.logger\.debug
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

Comment: I'll guess that you don't have subprocesses being measured properly. You can examine the data files that are produced during the run.  How many do you get, and what lines are they covering?  You can see a summary of the data with:  "COVERAGE_FILE=the_data_file coverage debug data"

Comment: @NedBatchelder I only get one file `.coverage.serval.TLD.12116.528573` which only contains part of the data. The final report is indeed correct and matches the data in that one file. I am assuming that there should be X (=NPROCS) files. I wonder if it is the django plugin that is not working right?…

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You miss a few steps, from [Measuring sub-processes](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html):

1. change the *coverage run* command to this one :

```sh
    COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=./.coveragerc-app coverage run 
    --parallel-mode --concurrency=multiprocessing 
    --rcfile=./.coveragerc-app manage.py test -v 3 --parallel=$(NPROCS) app
```

2. Create a file named *sitecustomize.py* in your local folder with

```
    import coverage
    coverage.process_startup()
```

3. Add concurrency option in your rcfile (run section):

```
    concurrency=multiprocessing
```

Comment: Happy to read that ! I have removed the fact that it may be optional

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that the concurrency option should be added to the [run] section of the coverage rc file.

Comment: The link is broken. The new one is: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.1.2/subprocess.html

Answer (score 8):

Took a read through the coverage documentation linked in answer above, perhaps it's been updated, as just doing the following seems to work for our Django project:

```sh
coverage run --concurrency=multiprocessing manage.py test app --parallel=3
coverage combine
coverage report
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#code-coverage):

> Coverage should be run in a single process to obtain accurate statistics.

Not an answer to this question but for those looking to optimize their project in this manner it may be helpful to know it isn't recommended by Django maintainers.

Comment: Urgh. That's lame. My tests take around 10/15 minutes to all run so parallel running is kinda needed.

Comment: That is the contributor documentation, stating how to run the django project tests before submitting a PR. It does not apply to individual projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```bash
function cpu_count() {
  python -c 'import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())'
}

function apps() {
  python -c "from website import apps; print(' '.join(apps.LOCAL_APPS))"
}

export $(cat envs/.env.development | xargs)

rm -rf htmlcov &&\
 coverage run --concurrency=multiprocessing\
  manage.py test --parallel $(cpu_count) $(apps) $@ &&\
 coverage combine &&\
 coverage html
```